# React Element appearing after second button click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, rendering

Im fairly new to react and im trying to build a webapp. I'm having this problem when it comes to displaying a div that contains multiple input fields, the field lesson dont show until the second time I click my create button. However it's working perfectly when I render it with this code:

Note: Im rendering TestClonereact in CourseVideoStructure

This is CourseVideoStructure.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Sidenavbar from '../../Components/Sidenavbar'
import '../../Style/pagestyle/CourseVideoStructure.css'
import Footer from '../../Components/Footer'
import { Avatar } from '@material-ui/core'
import 'react-dropzone-uploader/dist/styles.css'
import EdiText from 'react-editext'
import TestClonereact from '../../Components/TestClonereact'






export default class CourseVideoStructure extends Component {


    onSave = val => {
        console.log('Edited Value -> ', val)
    }
    id = 1;

    state = {
        listq: [],
    }
    lessons(id) {
        return (

            <div key={id} id={`sectionlesson-${id}`}>
                <div className="section-titles">
                    <i class="material-icons" id="iconsectionlist" type="button" >list</i>

                    <EdiText
                        type='text'
                        value='Lesson Title'
                        onSave={this.onSave}
                    />

                    <i class="material-icons" id="iconsectiondel" type="button">smart_display</i>
                    <i class="material-icons" id="iconsectiondel" onClick={e => this.remove(`${id}`)} type="button" >delete</i>

                </div>
                <div className="testh" >



                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
  

    addlesson1 = () => {

        const listlesson = this.state.listq;
        listlesson.push(this.lessons(this.id))
        this.setState({ listlesson });
        this.id++;
    }

    remove(id) {
        const newList = this.state.listq.filter(lessons => lessons.key !== id);
        this.setState({
            listq: newList
        })
    }

   addsection = () => {
        const list = this.state.list;
        list.push(this.section(this.id))
        this.setState({ list });
        this.id++;
      
    }

 


    render() {



        return (
            <div>
                <Sidenavbar></Sidenavbar>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md  navbar-white">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>

                    <Avatar className="avatar" aria-controls="simple-menu" aria-haspopup="true" src="https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/56764954?s=400&u=57d85794b8c753245870e2f9051b303d1188b01d&v=4" ></Avatar>

                </nav>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="fluid-xld" id="coursevideo-structure-xld">
                        <div className="course-structure-form-dsp col-md-12">
                            <h3 className="container"> Video Course Structure</h3><br></br><br></br>

                            <div className="course-structure-form " id="csf1">

                                <div className="section-heading">

                                    <i class="material-icons" id="iconsection">api</i>

                                    <EdiText
                                        type='text'
                                        value='Section Title'
                                        onSave={this.onSave}
                                    />


                                </div>
                                {
                                    this.state.listq.map(lessons => lessons)
                                }

                                <div className="addnewlesson" onClick={e => this.addlesson1()}>
                                    <i class="material-icons" id="iconsectionde" role="button" type="button" >add_circle</i><span>Add New Lesson</span>
                                    
                                </div>

                               

                            </div>


                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <TestClonereact></TestClonereact>
                        </div>

                     
                        

                    </div>
                   

                </div>
                <Footer></Footer>
            </div>
        )

    }
}
```

However when I try to render this component in CourseVideoStructure(the code above) it doesnt render as I would like it to:
This is TestClonereact.jsx:

```
import React, {useEffect, useReducer} from 'react'
import '../Style/pagestyle/CourseVideoStructure.css'
import EdiText from 'react-editext'


class TestClonereact extends React.Component {
    
  
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        listq: [],
        list: []
    };
 
  }


    onSave = val => {
        console.log('Edited Value -> ', val)
    }
    id = 1;


    
    lessons(id){
        return (

            <div key={id} id={`sectionlesson-${id}`}>
                <div className="section-titles">
                    <i class="material-icons" id="iconsectionlist" type="button" >list</i>

                    <EdiText
                        type='text'
                        value='Lesson Title'
                        onSave={this.onSave}
                    />

                    <i class="material-icons" id="iconsectiondel" type="button">smart_display</i>
                    <i class="material-icons" id="iconsectiondel" onClick={e => this.remove(`${id}`)} type="button" >delete</i>

                </div>
                <div className="testh" >



                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
 
     section(id){
        return (
            <div key={id} id={`sds-${id}`}>



                <div className="course-structure-form " id="csf1">

                    <div className="section-heading">

                        <i class="material-icons" id="iconsection">api</i>

                        <EdiText
                            type='text'
                            value='Section Title'
                            onSave={this.onSave}
                        />


                    </div>

                    {
                        this.state.listq.map(lessons => lessons)
                    }



                    <div className="addnewlesson" onClick={async ()  => { this.addlesson();}}>
                        <i class="material-icons" id="iconsectionde" role="button" type="button" >add_circle</i><span>Add New Lesson</span>
                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>
        )
    }


  addsection =   () => {
       const list = this.state.list;
       list.push(this.section(this.id))
       this.setState({ list });
       this.id++;
    
    }
    

    addlesson =  () =>  {
        const listlesson = this.state.listq;
        listlesson.push(this.lessons(this.id))
        this.setState({ listlesson });
        this.id++;
       
        
        }

  
  deletelesson =  () =>  {
        const list = this.state.list;
        list.splice(this.section(this.id))
        this.setState({ list });
        this.id--;
    }
  remove(id) {
        const newList = this.state.listq.filter(lessons => lessons.key !== id);
        this.setState({
            listq: newList
        })
    }


   
render(){

  
        return (
            <div>


                {
                    this.state.list.map(section => section)

                }

                <div className="add-section-button-structure">
                <button class="tablink" onClick={e => this.addsection()} >Add New Section</button>
                   
                    <button class="tablink" onClick={e => this.deletelesson()} >Delete Section</button>
                    <button class="tablink" >Preview</button>
                    <button class="tablink" >Submit</button>
                </div>

            </div>)


    }



}

export default TestClonereact
```

So the result in images is this:

Working fine and Added Lessons 1 by 1 in the same Section:
[Working Fine and able to add lessons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzWHi.png)

Problem is when I click on Add Lesson in the Second section, nothing happens but when I click on Add section again, the lesson appear in the 3rd section not the second one:
[Problem image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdM6j.png)

I've kept tryint to solve this issue with no luck. Any kind of help is much appreciated.
Forgive me for any horrible coding.

Comment: Why do you have `window.addEventListener("change", function (event) {` on window?
Also what are you trying to achive by storing react components in `listq` state?

Comment: @TJ The window.addEventListener was from my old code I deleted it. With listq im trying to store an array of my lessons div ( lessons(id) { html code here}) and then mapping it in the return so everytime i click the button add lesson it keeps adding 1 lesson/click.

Comment: So the lesson component doesn't need any dynamic data? imo you should store the data and then render a component to display the stored data

Comment: @Tj That's what I'm doing in the second part  when im using this:  {this.state.listq.map(lessons => lessons), is this what you mean ?